# Splitting a sentence where lower case and upper case are joint

Tags: python, string, list

I have a **list of sentences** where the lower case of a word is joint to the upper case of the next word like 'AvailableIndoor' as shown below:

```
'Full Bar Available  Valet Parking AvailableIndoor SeatingWifiTable reservation required'
```

I want to split at those instances and replace it with double space ("  ") something like this

```
'Full Bar Available  Valet Parking Available  Indoor Seating  Wifi  Table reservation required'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex substitution is one thing, but if you don't understand regex, there is a way to do this without importing any libraries. Might not be the most efficient way but it works.

```py
s = 'Full Bar Available  Valet Parking AvailableIndoor SeatingWifiTable reservation required'
fin = []
i = 1 # We want to start from 1 due to how our if condition is structured
fin.append(s[0]) # Since we're starting from the 1st (not 0th) position, we have 
                 # to manually add it to our final list outside of the loop

while i < len(s): # len(s) to check over the entire length of the string
    if s[i].istitle() and not s[i-1].istitle() and s[i-1] != ' ':
    # If the previous letter was lower case and the current one is upper case,
    # and also the previous isn't a space, we separate them by 2 spaces
        fin.append("  ")
        fin.append(s[i])
        i += 1
    else:
        fin.append(s[i])
        i += 1

print(''.join(fin)) # This just joins all the elements of our list 'fin' into 
                    #one, without any additional characters between each element
```

I think this is pretty easy to understand so you can later make your own code for various other situations. Just some basic loop and list operations.

Answer (score 2):

With regex substitution:

```
import re

s = 'Full Bar Available  Valet Parking AvailableIndoor SeatingWifiTable reservation required'
res = re.sub(r'([a-z])([A-Z])', r'\1  \2', s)
print(res)
```

- `\1` and `\2` - reference to the respective captured groups (`([a-z])` and `([A-Z])`)

---

The output:

```
Full Bar Available  Valet Parking Available  Indoor Seating  Wifi  Table reservation required
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative `re.findall` solution:

```
import re
s = 'Full Bar Available  Valet Parking AvailableIndoor SeatingWifiTable reservation required'
new_s = '  '.join(re.findall('[A-Z][a-z]+|[a-z]+', s))
```

Output:

```
'Full  Bar  Available  Valet  Parking  Available  Indoor  Seating  Wifi  Table  reservation  required'
```